# what is the most efficient way to stream videos in android app

Tags: android, streaming

I am Building An app for on line streaming,using MediaPayer to stream videos,

```
player.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(getLink()));
```

but his seems rather slow ,is there more efficient way to stream videos ,please guide 
thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

> is there more efficient way to stream videos ?

You could try using the `VideoView` class: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html

> Displays a video file. The VideoView class can load images from
>   various sources (such as resources or content providers), takes care
>   of computing its measurement from the video so that it can be used in
>   any layout manager, and provides various display options such as
>   scaling and tinting.

or if you are willing to write some boiler plate code (mostly using dependency injection) you could try `ExoPlayer`.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html

There is some excellent sample code in GitHub for ExoPlayer as well to get you started.